# HTML video with css position fixed and background-attachment fixed on chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I have a video with position fixed and a couple of div with background-attachment fixed.
Everything works fine in firefox and IE but with chrome, the background images don't display well.

http://jsfiddle.net/V74WH/2/

HTML:

```
 <video class="sleep-video" autoplay>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 </video>

 <div class="section one"></div>
 <div class="section two"></div>
 <div class="section three"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    body, html {
      padding: 0;
      margin:0;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .section {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      position: relative;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .section.one,
    .section.three {
      background-image: url(http://www.maximumpc.com/files/u160391/chrome_0.png);
    }

    .section.two {
      background: none;
    }

    .sleep-video {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

I absolutely need to have background-attachment fixed for the images because my site use parallax effects. Currently, the workaround that I use is to hide the video when I don't need it but it's far from ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your z-index on the video may be causing issues. Try putting it behind. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V74WH/4/)

```
  .sleep-video {
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -20;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Also had to put -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); for better performance.

Comment: This is no solution, the background-attachment scrolls and it is not fixed as is requested.